Error en método PUT con Angular + .Net Core Web API
Necesito de sus conocimientos. Tengo un error y hace días no le encuentro la falla.
Estoy haciendo un CRUD de Empleados con Angular 17 mo-standalone y Asp.Net Core Web API 8
En el CRUD tanto el CREATE como el DELETE funcionan perfecto en el código, pero el EDIT me está dando error. Les dejo el código del submit del formulario junto con el código de update (que están ambos en el mismo archivo: empleados-form.component.ts)
submit(form:NgForm)
  {
    this.empService.empleadosData.estadoCivil=form.value.isMarried==true?1:0;
    this.empService.empleadosData.estado=form.value.isActive==true?1:0;
    if(this.empService.empleadosData.id==0){
      this.insertarEmpleado(form);
    } else {
      this.updateEmpl(form);      CONSOLE ME ARROJA AQUÍ ERROR
    }
  }


updateEmpl(myform:NgForm)
  {
    this.empService.updateEmpleados().subscribe(d=>{       CONSOLA ME ARROJA AQUÍ ERROR
        this.resetForm(myform);
      this.refereshData();
      console.log('Actualizado con éxito')
    });
  }

y en el empleados-form.component.html (donde está el formulario para crear y editar) me arroja el siguiente error en el siguiente fragmento:
<div class="formAdd">
    <form autocomplete="off" #myForm="ngForm" (submit)="myForm.form.valid && submit(myForm)">

Donde está el error en el UPDATE del .ts en relación con el error en el .html del formulario ?????

y el error es que te arroja es....?

A esto le falta código y el error para saber que estás haciendo, por otro lado explicar más.

Falta que añadas el código de error como te han indicado y el código de tu servicio angular para que podamos ayudarte.
